How to replace the decimal number with a specific number in Excel automatically?
I want to replace the decimal number with a specific number in Excel automatically.  For example, replace the number 750.1...249 with 750.250 (the .... represents that the number can be 1 or 2 , it can be any numbers from 1 to 249)
replace the number 750.251...499 with 750.500 automatically
replace the number 750.501...749 with 750.750 automatically
I know I need to use And IF here for apply these situations but I don't know if it is possible to do like the conditions in the example above. I will really appreciate any help.

Does this work for you?  =SUM(INT(A1),CEILING.MATH(MOD(A1,1)*1000,250)/1000)

I found a video that answered my question and I am posting it for your benefit.... specially by using vlookup function
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UcDMke1kzhU

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
